# Objective-C Memory Issue with NSArray literal using NSNumber object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsarray

I have started out with Objective-C recently and trying to understand the memory management. I came across a peculiar problem yesterday which was causing a memory leak of over 150MB! I traced it down to a piece of code that was creating NSArray literal of NSNumbers. I managed to solve the issue using NSMutableArray (using addObject), but I haven't been able to grasp the concept as to why one method works and the other doesn't. I would love for someone with a better understanding of the memory management to explain the concept behind it so that I can avoid such mistakes in the future.

To better illustrate my question, let me also provide the code snippets. So for instance, I have a function that creates a NSArray of few NSNumbers and returns it and it gets called many times:

```
-(NSArray *)getNSNumberArray
{
    float num1 = 23.56;
    float num2 = 75.34;
    float num3 = 223.56;

    NSArray *numArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:num1], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num2], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num3]];
    return numArray;
}

-(void)causeMemoryLeak
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
    {
        NSArray *recieverArray = [self getNSNumberArray];
    }
}
```

This results in memory being occupied to be more than 200MB on an iphone6. However if I change my function to be:

```
-(NSArray *)getNSNumberArray
{
    float num1 = 23.56;
    float num2 = 75.34;
    float num3 = 223.56;

    NSMutableArray *numMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSNumber *nsNumber1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num1];
    NSNumber *nsNumber2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num2];
    NSNumber *nsNumber3 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num3];
    [numMutableArray addObject:nsNumber1];
    [numMutableArray addObject:nsNumber2];
    [numMutableArray addObject:nsNumber3];
    return numMutableArray;
}

-(void)causeMemoryLeak
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
    {
        NSArray *recieverArray = [self getNSNumberArray];
    }
}
```

This does not cause any memory issues.

Maybe I am missing something very obvious, but still cant figure out the reason behind this. Would really appreciate the help on this. There could also be better ways of doing it, and such answers are welcome but basically I am looking for an explanation behind it.

Many thanks in advance!

Attaching links to screenshots showing the memory allocation on device (iphone 6) (I can not attach images here as of now, so have to provide links)

Approach 1 Memory Allocation (memory is retained and not freed up): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-a9WJSBuIL4bTR5RTVuaWpqYkE&authuser=0

Approach 2 Memory Allocation (memory is freed up and there is no surge in memory allocation as well): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-a9WJSBuIL4QzQzbGYyQzZDdW8&authuser=0

Comment: 1. Use double, not float, unless you have a convincing reason to use float. 2. The array should be created as @[@(num1),@(num2),@(num3)].

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, only one approach is causing surge in memory, it does not seem so. According to the documentation, NSMutableArray uses slightly more memory because it can change size, it can't store the contents inside the object and must store a pointer to out of line storage as well as the extra malloc node for the storage.

In both the approaches, memory is freed up instantly, there is no issue with me.

**Update 1** :

I have noticed that if you use the array, for example if you log the array, the memory is freed up instantly in your first approach. It is happening as you do not use that array. It solves your problem.Try this code :

```
-(NSArray *)getNSNumberArray
{
    float num1 = 23.56;
    float num2 = 75.34;
    float num3 = 223.56;

    NSArray *numArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:num1], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num2], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:num3]];
    return numArray;
}

-(void)causeMemoryLeak
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
    {
        NSArray *recieverArray = [self getNSNumberArray];
        NSLog(@"%@", recieverArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2000000 calls are just to show the appreciable memory leak. In both the approaches the function is being called 2000000 times. I have just changed the function body in the two approaches. Problem is that in the first approach, memory is being retained and not freed up while it gets freed up in the second one. Trying to figure out the reason behind it.

Comment: @IndieGameDevLearner Check the updated answer. I have added screenshot and i am getting 200+ mb memory for both the approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Have you tested it out on an actual device or simulator? (I get a different result on the simulator but it is the device one that is more important).I have attached screenshots to the question that I see.

Comment: Also - "Both of the approaches are creating memory leaks as you are looping so many times" - Can you elaborate why looping should cause memory leaks? I am not keeping any strong pointers as far as I can see, so the memory should be freed up in the next run. This is happening (atleast for me) when I use NSMutableArray. The memory gets freed up instantly in every run and there is no surge in memory as well. This is what has got me confused as there really should be no memory surge and no memory leak as per my understanding. Any light on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @IndieGameDevLearner Check my update in the answer. If you use the array, the memory gets freed up instantly. Upvote and mark as correct if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for trying that out, and you are correct, the memory does free up instantly. But anyways, my question is not to make this approach work, but to actually understand why NSArray does not free up instantly but NSMutableArray does (or why does the NSLog statement work??) in order to get a better understanding of the memory management. gnasher729 has led to the right path that it has to with the use of @autoreleasepool and if you can use that and provide me the difference between the two approaches, I would happily mark your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code because I really didn't found any reason for memory leak and there is no memory leak.

When you use the regular array, the device runs all the code, and releases the memory only at the end. This causing the heap to alloc 250 MB, and release them at the end.

If you use the mutable array, the device releases the previous array before creating the new one, so there is no point with to many allocation.

I guess that the different may be caused by run time complexity of the called function in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The trouble is I do get a memory leak which is why it is so confusing.  I have attached the screenshots to the question.

Comment: Also, why would the device release the entire memory at the end for a NSArray and not for NSMutableArray? Is there some documentation on this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did the app crashed? stucked? About the NSMutableArray, I'm guessing that because of the adding new object to the array, the device is releasing previous memory in the middle. If you will construct the mutable array with all the object at the beginning, you will see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to read up on "autorelease" and "autorelease pools". Objects often are kept inside an autorelease pool and only disappear when the autorelease pool disappears. So a loop iterating two million times without using an autorelease pool is a bad, bad idea. You don't actually have a memory leak, the objects will all be released some time after the method returns.

Most methods returning objects return autoreleased objects, but the result of [[xxx alloc] init] is not autoreleased, so there you have the difference. But also ARC is quite clever, and if a method returns an autoreleased object and the caller immediately retains the object, the object will not actually be added to the autorelease pool. That's what happened when the object was passed to NSLog; in order to do that, it had to be retained first. No autorelease pool. In your code, the object was never used, so that optimisation didn't happened.

Of course your code is really useless, so you were punished for writing useless code.

Comment: First of all, this is a just a test scenario code and as such it's only purpose is to replicate a basic scenario and beyond that it is supposed to be useless. This is the toned down version of the "actual useful" code which was giving the problem so I was also punished for writing useful code!

Comment: Following on from your answer, what I gather is that there is no 'memory-leak' as such but since I don't have @autoreleasepool, the memory would be released gradually and not instantly but I can not guarantee when the memory would be completely released? Is that bit correct? If so, why is a NSMutableArray freed up instantly but not NSArray? Is there some magic in the 'addObject' method? And a basic question that pops up - When to use @autoreleasepool? Is there any best practice around it? Should it be a standard within iterative loops or should it just be used within long running loops?